# Determining the hash type I am working with for use in hashcat

Tags: brute-force, hashcat

I am trying to crack some hashed information because the passcode was lost to us. I have the hashed information in the database, and the code that was used to encrypt it. It goes through cryptastic which appears to use rijndael-256 and pbkdf2, as far as my ignorant self can tell:

public function encrypt($msg, $k, $base64 = false)
    {

```
    # open cipher module (do not change cipher/mode)
    if (!$td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-256', '', 'ctr', ''))
        return false;

    $msg = serialize($msg);                         # serialize
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_RAND);        # create iv

    if (mcrypt_generic_init($td, $k, $iv) !== 0)  # initialize buffers
        return false;

    $msg = mcrypt_generic($td, $msg);               # encrypt
    $msg = $iv . $msg;                              # prepend iv
    $mac = $this->pbkdf2($msg, $k, 1000, 32, 'sha256');       # create mac
    $msg .= $mac;                                   # append mac

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);                     # clear buffers
    mcrypt_module_close($td);                       # close cipher module

    if ($base64)
        $msg = base64_encode($msg);# base64 encode?

    return $msg;                                    # return iv+ciphertext+mac
}
```

And in the end looks like this: wWTWLPvXT9YRz2Zj+Og0EwTTSEiZGdjAQ1TRhycJA9jusjQ2mTpptw3hSM1XJ9yPw+4XvsvFASe08AbLr3BT0LFnvGsYPrq87yI= (I know this to be a 3 digit number if that helps at all)

So I am trying to use hashcat to recover our information and I am not certain I am using the correct hash-type. I am checking this page here: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes and searching for 'pbkdf2' and looking at all the hits.

The best match as far as I can tell is 9200/Cisco-IOS $8$ (PBKDF2-SHA256) except that that seems to have a header of $8$, and none of my information has any headers at all, and no $ characters. Everything else with PBKDF2 in it doesn't seem to be a match either so I find myself kind of lost before I've even gotten started.

I also noticed my hashed info always had == on the end, but only for the longer information being encrypted, in the list Juniper IVE seems to fit that format but the name doesn't match anything I can see in cryptastic.

I'm mostly ready to go aside from this as far as I can tell, I have my custom rules set up since I know how we create the initial passcodes and the hashes are in a file to be read, it's just this hash-type selection that is blocking me.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Two things:

That string you posted is indeed likely to be base64 encoded (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/245220/237355).
Because it is base64 encoded, you will need to decode it to crack it. Except I tried decoding it (plenty of online sites that do this) and it said it was invalid base64. Which leads to my second thing, can you try and find a better place to get the hash? Possibly via the server itself? Here's an example of what I mean: https://cqureacademy.com/blog/secure-server/extract-hashes-sql-server-logins, there should be a way to find the actual hash.

Comment: Wait a second. If you know it's a 3 digit number for the password, it might be faster just to write a quick script to bruteforce the password. This is probably the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Ah, sorry the password is not a 3 digit number, but rather the encrypted info I gave as an example is. The password we're using is a ten digit random number. You put me on a path that lead to this though: https://ipsec.pl/2013/php-cryptography-proceed-care.html. In my example up there it is doing 1000 iterations, and the decryption is doing the same which prevented me from brute forcing it effectively. The article points out that the 1000 iterations are unnecessary during validation so I changed it to 1 and and so I should now be able to brute force it. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent! Would love to hear when it works :) and if it does, you can probably write and accept your own answer.

Comment: @AndrewZick I really, really should have done a check after reading that with my own dummy information encrypted and de-crypted. Changing the iterations to 1 changes the returned value and it no longer decrypts properly. I encrypted a dummy string with 1000 iterations and it looks like it needs 1000 iterations to decrypt too :(